# How do I move sharepoint wiki pages from one library to another library?

Tags: library, sharepoint-library, content-migration

I am using SharePoint 365 (at least I think this is the version...it is entirely web based) and am trying to control access to certain wiki pages.  I figured the best way to do this is create a library with all of the wiki pages in it and then grant the appropriate access to that library.  The problem is that I already created some wiki pages in the main library.  How do I move my existing wiki pages from the default site library to the new library I created?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download and upload.
2. You can use the Windows Explorer view.
3. You can write PowerShell PnP (client side) script to copy items from one library to the other.